# ssrs not want final page break

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

In a new SSRS 2008 report, I have one main tablix and I will be embedding 5 existing tablixes into the one main tablix. For each row in the main tablix, I will be embedding 1 of the tablixes. There will be one dataset used and the same parameters are used between the 5 existing embedded tablixes. One of the parameters is to allow the user to select report number 1,2,3,4, or 5 which is an integer value. The default will be to select all the reports.

The selection of which reports will be displayed will be from the main tablix on row visibility for each embedded tablix. Each tablix will be set to 'add a page break after'. This works fine except the last page of the last report will always have a final blank page. I basically do not want that final page break to appear.

Thus is there a way to not have the final page break show up? Could I use some kind of condtional page break logic? If there some kind of a way to determine what the highest number report is that is selected and not allow a final page break to occur in that situation. If so, how would you setup that code?

If not, can you tell me a way that will solve this issue and show me the code, show me the screen prints, and or point me to link(s) that will tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is two option for page break...One is Start of group and another one is end of group. Tick the start of a group only ...don't select end of a group. Let me know if you need any more help on this...

Comment: If I check start of group, there will always be a blank page at first not at the end. Thus that just changes the problem. Remember that the user can select any 1 report alone. There would always be a page break at first. What else do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

For each tablix you set "add a page break after", you need to select the tablix and go to Properties pane and expand page break section. Under the page break section you can enter an expression for the Disabled property.

Assuming your SelectReportNumber parameter is single select and Null displays all reports, the expressions for first four tablix should be like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!SelectReportNumber.Value <> Nothing,True,False)
```

Last tablix should not have page break in any case.

If you need multi select then you need to modify the expression for determining Max of the parameter and disable that page break only.